# Obtaining data on clicking multiple radio buttons in a page using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium

I have a page, and I have 3 radio buttons on it. I want my code to consecutively click each of these buttons, and as they are clicked, a value (mpn) is displayed, I want to obtain this value. I am able to write the code for a single radio button, but I dont understand how i can create a loop so that only value of this button changes (value={1,2,3})

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Home\Desktop\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.1800cpap.com/resmed-airfit-n30-nasal-cpap-mask-with-headgear")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

size=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='product-views-option-tile-input-picker'and @value='2' ]")
size.click()
mpn= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='mpn-value']")
print(mpn.text)
```

Also, for each page, the buttons vary in number, and their names. So, if there is any general solution that i could extend to all pages, for all buttons, it would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

You were a small step from the correct solution! In particular, the `find_element_by_xpath()` function returns a single element, but the similar function `find_elements_by_xpath()` (mind the plural) returns an iterable list, which you can use to implement a for loop.

Below a MWE with the example page that you provided

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox() # initiate the driver

driver.get("https://www.1800cpap.com/resmed-airfit-n30-nasal-cpap-mask-with-headgear")

time.sleep(2) # sleep for a couple seconds to ensure correct upload

mpn = [] # initiate an empty results' list
for button in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//label[@data-label='label-custcol3']"):
    button.click()    
    mpn.append(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='mpn-value']").text)

print(mpn) # print results
```

Comment: Hi, what do you mean exactly? Looping through different urls is straighrforward: you create a list of urls, and loop through it, changing every time the value within `driver.get()`.

Comment: P. S. beware that webdriver needs some time to upload: use time.sleep() for 1 or 2 secs between two pages